# Best/Fast way to remove a column from a Python 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter

I have a list of list of lists (all of lists have same size) in python like this:

```
A = [[1,2,3,4],['a','b','c','d'] , [12,13,14,15]]
```

I want to remove some columns (i-th elements of all lists).

Is there any  way that does this without `for` statements?

Comment: with numpy yes. Else, you need at least 1 `for`

Comment: Why would you want to do it without a for statement? Of course you can replace for loops with while loops but that will only make your code less readable

Comment: Fundamentally, even numpy uses a loop implementation. Although to be pedantic, we can use a `while` loop here to do it too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, you can't do this without loop. However, using built-in functions here's a functional approach that doesn't explicitly use any loop:

```
In [24]: from operator import itemgetter

In [25]: def remove_col(arr, ith):
    ...:     itg = itemgetter(*filter((ith).__ne__, range(len(arr[0]))))
    ...:     return list(map(list, map(itg, arr)))
    ...:
```

Demo:

```
In [26]: remove_col(A, 1)
Out[26]: [[1, 3, 4], ['a', 'c', 'd'], [12, 14, 15]]

In [27]: remove_col(A, 3)
Out[27]: [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [12, 13, 14]]
```

Note that instead of `list(map(list, map(itg, arr)))` if you only return `map(itg, arr)` it will give you the expected result but as an iterator of iterators instead of list of lists. This will be a more optimized approach in terms of both memory and run-time in this case.

Also, using loops here's the way I'd do this:

```
In [31]: def remove_col(arr, ith):
    ...:     return [[j for i,j in enumerate(sub) if i != ith] for sub in arr]
```

Surprisingly (not if you believe in the power of C :)) the functional approach is even faster for large arrays.

```
In [41]: arr = A * 10000

In [42]: %timeit remove_col_functional(arr, 2)
8.42 ms ± 37.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [43]: %timeit remove_col_list_com(arr, 2)
23.7 ms ± 165 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# And if in functional approach you just return map(itg, arr)
In [47]: %timeit remove_col_functional_iterator(arr, 2)
1.48 µs ± 4.71 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: I _really_ like your "using loops" approach... almost like something [I might come up with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54503419/1639625). :-P

Comment: Hm, did not expect that. Although, when I test it, the difference is not quite as dramatic. Also, IMHO timing the iterator-creation is kind of silly, you can't really compare those.

Comment: @tobias_k Of course, it's there just as a prof to the aforementioned explanation. Regarding the difference it's not that dramatic here too, and don't be suprised because that's the power of C and the law of [leaky abstractions](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/).

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do this without `for` if you are proficient with `zip` (it's my favorite "hack"):

```
A = [[1, 2, 3, 4], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
B = list(zip(*A))
B.pop(i)
C = list(map(list, zip(*B)))
```

Result (i = 2):

```
[[1, 2, 4], ['a', 'b', 'd'], [12, 13, 15]]
```

---

Of course, `map` is an alternative to list comprehension:

```
B = list(map(lambda l: l[:i] + l[i + 1:], A))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that performance suffers compared to standard comprension because of all temp objects created. But I could be wrong. And `map(lambda` is not recommended

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sure you're right, but `zip` and `map` objects should be comparable to generators (but not list comprehensions).

Answer (score 3):

`numpy` is able to remove entire columns:

```
import numpy

A = [[1,2,3,4],['a','b','c','d'] , [12,13,14,15]]

na = numpy.array(A)

print(na[:,:-1])   # remove last column
print(na[:,1:])    # remove first column

print(numpy.concatenate((na[:,:2],na[:,3:]),axis=1)) # build from 2 slices: remove third column
```

result (simplicity's sake: all data have been converted to string, no `dtype` involved):

```
[['1' '2' '3']
 ['a' 'b' 'c']
 ['12' '13' '14']]

[['2' '3' '4']
 ['b' 'c' 'd']
 ['13' '14' '15']]

[['1' '2' '4']
 ['a' 'b' 'd']
 ['12' '13' '15']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another variant using a list-comprehension, with `enumerate`:

```
>>> A = [[1,2,3,4],['a','b','c','d'] , [12,13,14,15]]
>>> k = 2
>>> [[x for i, x in enumerate(a) if i != k] for a in A]
[[1, 2, 4], ['a', 'b', 'd'], [12, 13, 15]]
```

And, yes, this has the word `for` in it (twice even!), but performance should not be different than for any of the other approaches (`numpy` might be faster, though).

Answer (score 2):

You could easily use [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and [slices](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) :

```
A = [[1,2,3,4],['a','b','c','d'] , [12,13,14,15]]
k = 1

B = [l[:k]+l[k+1:] for l in A]

print(B) # >> returns [[1, 3, 4], ['a', 'c', 'd'], [12, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: this still has a `for`, maybe you can include map?

Comment: List comprehension are not slower than mapping, and they are more readable... And I thought asker wanted to avoid the use of `for` loop, not of any O(1) loop...

Comment: @olinox14 I agree that the request for "no for loops" is kind of pointless, since all the other approaches have loops somethere hidden inside, too, but what is a "O(1) loop"?

Comment: It is the standard way to measure the complexity of an algorithm, take a look [here](https://adrianmejia.com/blog/2014/02/13/algorithms-for-dummies-part-1-sorting/) or [here](https://discrete.gr/complexity/)